# Controlling wget with PHP

Tags: php, process, fork, wget, download

I’m writing a command line PHP console script to watch for new URLs and launch (large) downloads for a client’s project I am working on. The client is currently manually downloading them with a slightly specific wget command and ideally would like to stay with that.

I was wondering what the best way to call wget from PHP would be and to watch for either a completed download or any errors that come along. At the moment, I’m using a basic shell_exec however this isn’t suitable for a production environment.

Any suggestions at all would be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find http://www.saynotoflash.com/archives/php-tutorial-forking-using-wget-in-the-background/ informative.

Answer (score 3):

Something you might want to consider is using curl instead of wget. libcurl is integrated into PHP well - with all the shabang of error reporting.

Comment: The only problem with cURL is that I’m not too sure how it would stand up with larger downloads and the specific needs of my client.

Comment: I've used curl with multi-dozen-megabyte downloads; curl can support almost anything any other HTTP client can support (cookies, HTTPS, etc)

Comment: Could you provide some example code, specifically on file downloads?